# Laravel migrate cannot add foregin key

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm trying to make migraions, but still have the same error :

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key 
constraint (SQL  
 : alter table `user_class` add constraint 
`user_class_class_id_foreign` 
foreign key (`class_id`) references `classes` (`id`))                           




[PDOException]                                                          
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key 
constraint
```

My database migrations are:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_class', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('class_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('class_id')->references('id')->on('classes');
    });
}

public function down()
{

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    Schema::drop('user_class');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');

}
```

I think that I have this error because user_classes are in my database file earlier then classes? Is it possible that this is my problem?

When i make : php artisan make:rollback - this table : user_class is not removing from my phpAdmin... only this

Comment: Yes, parent table has to be before to create child tables

Comment: Ok, so what should I do in this moment? How can I change order my tables?

Comment: Just rename them, they are executed in the same order that they appear in the project files tree

Comment: you should ensure to clear your migrations table before changing names. Otherwise you will run into file not found errors

Comment: make sure `user` and `classes` create first.. then `user_classes`

Answer (score 0):

I think length method is the problem, I checked Laravel documentation and it doesn't exist.